# How to retrieve values from settings.bundle in TVML?

Tags: tvos, tvml, settings-bundle

In my tvOS app I created a settings bundle, but I don't know how to get the values in TVML. I know how to do it in Obj-c or Swift.

```
var standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var us: AnyObject? = standardUserDefaults.objectForKey("your_preference")
if us==nil {
    self.registerDefaultsFromSettingsBundle();
}
```

Any ideas about TVML way? Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a direct TVJS access method... but you could easily set up a Swift/Obj-C-"proxy". Somewhat along those lines:

AppDelegate.swift

```
func appController(appController: TVApplicationController, evaluateAppJavaScriptInContext jsContext: JSContext) {
    let jsInterface: cJsInterface = cJsInterface();
    jsContext.setObject(jsInterface, forKeyedSubscript: "swiftInterface")
}
```

JsInterface.swift

```
@objc protocol jsInterfaceProtocol : JSExport {
    func getSetting(setting: String) -> String
}
class cJsInterface: NSObject, jsInterfaceProtocol {
    func getSetting(setting: String) -> String {
        return "<yourSetting>"
    }
}
```

on the JS side...

```
swiftInterface.getSetting(...)
```